# Cordova - Content Security Policy Android Api 22

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, content-security-policy

I have an issue which i try to fix for 4 days.

I've created an application using phonegap. On android api 25 it works well, without any problem.

On android api 22, the javascript is not working at all. I figure it out that the CSP is the problem and i tried every combination of CSP rules but didn't work.

I even have https api calls.

Please, anyone could bring a solution to this?

EDIT:

This is how an apicall looks like :

```
 $.post('https://'+base+"."+url+'/apicall/token/_token', data, function(dataR){
                var json = JSON.parse(dataR);
                store.setJWT(json.tm, json.fg);

                var storage = window.localStorage;
                var onBoarding = storage.getItem("onboarding"); 
                if(onBoarding==null || onBoarding==0)setOnBoarding();



            }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                logThis("index", "customRandomizer", xhr.status, thrownError, xhr.responseText);
            });
```

And this is the meta tag i use for CSP:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline' gap: ws: https://ssl.gstatic.com;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;media-src *;img-src * 'self' data: content:;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
```

Comment: Please add more information about your application

Comment: I attached some parts of code

Comment: Please add your exact error message